# Can't install phpMyAdmin in Centos 6.9 / PHP 7.0

Tags: phpmyadmin

Yesterday I updated to PHP 7 in two VPSs, one with Centos 7 and everything went ok, the other has Centos 6.9 and I'm not able to install phpMyAdmin (It was installed till the php update)

Most related output:

`$ yum install phpmyadmin
---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.0.10.19-1.el6 will be instalado
Error: php70w-common conflicts with php56w-common-5.6.30-1.w6.x86_64`

I suppose that phpMyAdmin 4.0 is obsolete to work with php7, the VPS running Centos 7 has phpMyAdmin 4.4, package that can't be found in Centos 6.9

**UPDATE:**

`$ php -v
PHP 7.0.19 (cli) (built: May 12 2017 21:20:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v6.0.9, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.19, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies`

Comment: remove php5, install php7 and then install phpmyadmin

Comment: `Error: php70w-common conflicts with php56w-common-5.6.30-1.w6.x86_64` is your answer.  You can't install PHP 7.0 on top of PHP 5.6

Comment: @h3rrmiller Yeah, but I got php7 already, not 5.6, I guess that the mentioned php5.6 is a dependance of pma 4.0, not my actual php version installed. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @RomeoNinov oh, didn't read that comment, well, as I said, I already have php7... Maybe I have to purge, clear some cache or refresh something?